# Heroku Failing to Build a Django App using Conda as the Environment

Tags: python, django, heroku, deployment, conda-build

**TL:DR:**
Django app failing build with logs pointing to '*Could not find a suitable TLS CA certificate bundle*' &  '*No module named 'conda.cli.main_info*'

**Details:**
Running into a Heroku build failing when pushing a python app (Django) with a conda env. Same code base + environment as the current build running on the Dyno - we have reverted back, made a syntax commit change, and tried pushing but it fails.

**Buildpack:** https://github.com/pl31/heroku-buildpack-conda

**Environment.yml**

```
name: *****
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - anaconda-fusion
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - asgiref=3.5.0
  - asn1crypto=1.3.0
  - ca-certificates=2022.6.15
  - certifi=2022.6.15
  - cffi=1.14.0
  - chardet=3.0.4
  - cryptography=2.8
  - dj-database-url=0.5.0
  - django=3.2.12
  - django-cors-headers=3.13.0
  - django-heroku=0.3.1
  - idna=2.9
  - krb5=1.16.4
  #  - libcxx=4.0.1
  #  - libcxxabi=4.0.1
  - libedit=3.1.20181209
  - libffi=3.2.1
  - libpq=11.2
  - libzlib=1.2.11
  - ncurses=6.1
  - openssl=1.1.1p
  - pexpect=4.8.0
  - pip=19.3.1
  - psycopg2=2.8.4
  - ptyprocess=0.6.0
  - pycparser=2.20
  - pyopenssl=19.1.0
  - pysocks=1.7.1
  - python=3.8.0
  - python_abi=3.8
  - pytz=2019.3
  - readline=7.0
  - requests=2.23.0
  - setuptools=42.0.2
  - sqlite=3.30.1
  - sqlparse=0.3.0
  - tk=8.6.8
  - typing_extensions=4.0.1
  - urllib3=1.25.8
  - wheel=0.33.6
  - whitenoise=5.3.0
  - xz=5.2.4
  - zlib=1.2.11
  - celery=5.2.1
  - redis-py=3.5.3
  - pip:
      - aniso8601==7.0.0
      - apscheduler==3.9.1
      - backports-zoneinfo==0.2.1
      - cachecontrol==0.12.11
      - cachetools==5.0.0
      - firebase-admin==5.2.0
      - google-api-core==2.7.2
      - google-api-python-client==2.45.0
      - google-auth==2.6.6
      - google-auth-httplib2==0.1.0
      - google-cloud-core==2.3.0
      - google-cloud-firestore==2.4.0
      - google-cloud-storage==2.3.0
      - google-crc32c==1.3.0
      - google-resumable-media==2.3.2
      - googleapis-common-protos==1.56.0
      - graphene==2.1.8
      - graphene-django==2.8.0
      - graphql-core==2.2.1
      - graphql-relay==2.0.1
      - grpcio==1.44.0
      - grpcio-status==1.44.0
      - gunicorn==20.1.0
      - httplib2==0.20.4
      - msgpack==1.0.3
      - promise==2.3
      - proto-plus==1.20.3
      - protobuf==3.20.1
      - pyasn1==0.4.8
      - pyasn1-modules==0.2.8
      - pyparsing==3.0.8
      - python-dotenv==0.20.0
      - pytz-deprecation-shim==0.1.0.post0
      - rsa==4.8
      - rx==1.6.1
      - singledispatch==3.4.0.3
      - six==1.13.0
      - tzdata==2022.1
      - tzlocal==4.2
      - uritemplate==4.1.1
```

**Error:** When I push the logs throw the following error

```
remote:   File "/app/.conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 263, in cert_verify
remote: OSError: Could not find a suitable TLS CA certificate bundle, invalid path: /app/.conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/certifi/cacert.pem


remote: During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
...
remote: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'conda.cli.main_info'
```